# Is it possible to have automatic reference in word by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a long list of reference that should be entered in MS word. something like this:

```
[1] Nudo, R. J., Milliken, G. W., and Jenkins, W. M. , “Use-dependent alterations of movement representations in primary motor cortex of adult squirrel monkeys,” The Journal of Neuroscience, vol. 16, no. 2, pp. 785–807, 1996.
Google Scholar | ISI
[2] Taub, E., Uswatte, G., and Elbert, T. , “New treatments in neurorehabilitation founded on basic research,” Nature Reviews Neuroscience, vol. 3, no. 3, pp. 228–236, 2002.
Google Scholar | Crossref | ISI
[3] Equal, KT , “Robots for rehabilitation,” http://rehabilitationrobotics.net/cms/?q=node/79.
Google Scholar
[4] Kahn, L. E., Lum, P. S., Rymer, W. Z., and Reinkensmeyer, D. J. , “Robot-assisted movement training for the stroke-impaired arm: does it matter what the robot does?” Journal of Rehabilitation Research and Development, vol. 43, no. 5, pp. 619–630, 2006.
Google Scholar | Crossref
[5] Kwakkel, G., Kollen, B. J., and Krebs, H. I. , “Effects of robot-assisted therapy on upper limb recovery after stroke: a systematic review,” Neurorehabilitation and Neural Repair, vol. 22, no. 2, pp. 111–121, 2008.
Google Scholar | SAGE Journals | ISI
```

It is really time consuming to enter all of the references (almost 300) in word by hand. I want to know if it's possible to have a python code that automatically connect to MS word and generate all the references?

how to fill out this by python?

[image]

Comment: it's unclear why copy/pasting isn't an option

Comment: Hi Paul, it's just very time consuming, and also by pasting I have only a plain text in ms word, I need to past it as Reference.

Comment: You want some library to manipulate docx file format. Perhaps antidocx?

Comment: You need software like zotero